# ffmpeg c# asp.net help on ProcessStartInfo

Tags: c#, asp.net, video, ffmpeg

I wrote the code to convert the file in c#asp.net using ffmpeg. While executing it shows error as "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect" but my paths are correct. So what is the solution for this?

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("e:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe", "-i cars1.flv -same_quant intermediate1.mpg");

process.Start();
```

I tried another way as shown below. But that is also won't works.

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("ffmpeg.exe", "-i cars1.flv -same_quant intermediate1.mpg");
```

Please help me with sample code for converting one video file format to another using ffmpeg in c# asp.net. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backslashes (`\`) in your path are considered to start [escape sequences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx).  To prevent this, either use double backslashes (`\\`), or prefix the string with `@`.

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("e:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe", 
                         "-i cars1.flv -same_quant intermediate1.mpg");
```

Or:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(@"e:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe", 
                         "-i cars1.flv -same_quant intermediate1.mpg");
```

Comment: Yep.. problem solved. Thank u dude. But i need some more help dude.

Comment: Now my exception contains the following message "StandardOut has not been redirected or the process hasn't started yet."

Answer (score 1):

There is wrapper library available

http://www.ffmpeg-csharp.com/

Also refer

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24995/FFMPEG-using-ASP-NET

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net+c%23+video

```
    string apppath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath; 

    string outf = Server.MapPath(".");

    string fileargs = "-i" + " " + "\"C:/file.mp4 \"" + " " + "\"C:/files/test.flv \"";

    Process myProcess = new Process();

    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = Server.MapPath(".")+"//ffmpeg.exe";

    myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = fileargs;

    myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

    myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;

    myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;

    myProcess.Start();

    myProcess.WaitForExit(50 * 1000);
```

Thanks

Deepu

Answer (score 0):

You need to have backslashes in your path see below this is how I create videos using ffmpeg.exe

```
        string sConverterPath = @"C:\ffmpeg.exe";
        string sConverterArguments = @" -i ";
        sConverterArguments += "\"" + sAVIFile + "\"";
        sConverterArguments += " -s " + iVideoWidth.ToString() + "x" + iVideoHeight.ToString() + " ";
        sConverterArguments += " -b " + iVideoBitRate.ToString() + "k -ab " + iAudioBitRate.ToString() + "k -ac 1 -ar 44100 -r 24 -absf remove_extra ";
        sConverterArguments += "\"" + sOutputFile + "\"";


        Process oProcess = new Process();
        oProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        oProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = sConverterArguments;
        oProcess.StartInfo.FileName = sConverterPath;
```

Comment: Please see my another question in ffmpeg. I post all code. Tell me what are the changes.