# How to extract Images from MP4 video on upload - FFMPEG

Tags: c#, asp.net, video, ffmpeg

I am putting together a training site for my company and we need to extract an image from each mp4 video we upload. I have searched lots and decided to try FFMPEG.

Here is what I have so far. I'm not getting errors, but no image in the specified folder.

Any help would be appreciated.

`string inputfile = Server.MapPath("/Report/TrainingLibrary/Material/Videos/RMSIMAILSignature.mp4");
            //string withouttext;
            string thumbpath;
            string thumbname;
            string thumbargs;
            //string thumbre;
           thumbpath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Reports\\ TrainingLibrary\\Material\\Videos\\";
            thumbname = thumbpath + "Image" + "%d" + ".jpg";
            thumbargs = "-i " + inputfile + " -vframes 1 -ss 00:00:07 -s 150x150 " + thumbname;
            Process thumbproc = new Process();
            thumbproc = new Process();
            thumbproc.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\FFMPEG\\Bin\\ffmpeg.exe";
            thumbproc.StartInfo.Arguments = thumbargs;
            thumbproc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            thumbproc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            thumbproc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
            try
            {
                thumbproc.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message);
            }
            thumbproc.WaitForExit();
            thumbproc.Close();`

Comment: Have you seen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431012/ffmpeg-c-sharp-asp-net-help-on-processstartinfo

Comment: Does it work if you run `ffmpeg` manually via command line? If yes, then the issue is with your script.